# How to change the controller path of a link in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How do I get:

```
<%= link_to 'Back', originalcontrollers_path %>
```

to be:

```
<%= link_to 'Back', modifiedcontrollers_path %>
```

I already have my route updated with:

```
get "modifiedcontrollers", :to => "originalcontrollers#index"
```

So the "/modifiedcontroller" url works the same as "/originalcontroller". When creating links I need it to point to the new url. How would I do this?

Comment: `Find and replce` in  your code editor? Or I've missed something in your plan

Comment: I could do that but what if I want my controller named something different from what I want it to be in my url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand you, but try this:

```
get "modifiedcontrollers", :to => "originalcontrollers#index", :as => :modifiedcontrollers
get "modifiedcontrollers/new", :to => "originalcontrollers#new", :as => :new_modifiedcontroller
...
```

so if you need all stack of routes:

```
resources :modifiedcontrollers, :controller => :originalcontrollers
```

so now this will work as expected

```
<%= link_to 'Back', modifiedcontrollers_path %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, fl00r - you understood what I was asking. Your solution works. Taking it a step further - I couldn't get this to work for me "<%= link_to 'New', new_modifiedcontrollers_path %>". When I use "<%= link_to 'New', new_originalcontrollers_path %>" it renders "/originalcontrollers/new".

Comment: you should specify this route as well

Comment: see my update `resources :modifiedcontrollers, :controller => :originalcontrollers`

Comment: it should be `:as => :new_modifiedcontroller`

Comment: It works. Thanks bro. I'm going to try a dynamic url to see if I can get it working. <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_modifiedcontrollers_path(@originalcontrollers) %>

Comment: `edit_modifiedcontroller_path` not `edit_modifiedcontrollers_path`. Singular form

Comment: So this `<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_originalcontroller_path(@originalcontroller) %>` renders this `/originalcontrollers/unique-id-here/edit` and this `<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_modifiedcontroller_path(@originalcontroller) %>` renders this `/modifiedcontroller/edit.unique-id-here`. The first path structure is correct - any ideas?

Comment: my routes look like this..  `resources :originalcontroller
  
  get "modifiedcontroller", :to => "originalcontroller#index" , :as => :modifiedcontroller
  get "modifiedcontroller/new", :to => "originalcontroller#new" , :as => :new_modifiedcontroller
  get "modifiedcontroller/edit", :to => "originalcontroller#edit" , :as => :edit_modifiedcontroller`

Comment: remove all this `modifiedcontroller...` and add this line as I've wroted `resources :modifiedcontrollers, :controller => :originalcontrollers`